# Excel VBA sub to fill a column with Countifs

Tags: excel, vba, countif, accounting

I want to automate a Sub routine to work on 15 000 rows. I have customer that either computer, vdi and other IT equipment. Each row is a record of the name of customer with the it equipment they have. I analyze the how many computer each customers have but for that I need to count duplicates. Basically I want to output the result fill it down to the last row( row change every time).

Thank you very much

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to copy paste a formula for an entire column?

Comment: `you want to count duplicates in a column`  ... all the other stuff that you said is irrelevant .... why can't you have formulas below the end of you data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is a simple 1-liner:

```
Range("N2:N" & Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=COUNTIFS(C[-3],RC[-3],C[-1],1)"
```